# Как создать окно с тулбаром без активити

Tags: android, activity

Я хочу создать окно для вывода результатов без создания новой активити.

Я пробовал использовать для этой цели `Dialog` с собственной разметкой и полноэкранной темой, но не смог сделать кнопку `back` в тулбаре.
Тогда я попробовал создать что-то свое, не расширяя класс `Dialog`, но не смог получить доступ к `PhoneWindow`, а других подклассов `Window` я не нашел.

Comment: По моему для этого отлично подойдет Fragment.

Comment: С фрагментами очень много геморроя, связанного с их жизненным циклом. Например, при повороте экрана фрагмент создается заново и не подключается к активити. (https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/)

Comment: @Соколов в итоге напишешь свой личный фрагмент(основы велосипедостроения)

Comment: @georgehardcore меня интересует, как создать свой класс типо полноэкранного диалога. Если не изобрести велосипед, никогда не поймешь как он устроен.